# Error to test subscriptions in signed debug app

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, google-play-console

I can't test subscriptions in my signed debug version, error:

[image]

Only works when I download the app straight from the store,

I have already done all these steps:

1 - The App is published in alpha;

2 - A test account is already registered on play console (Configurations);

3 - SKUs are already registered in play Console;

4 - Debug version code is same as store version;

5 - In Manifext android:debuggable="true" and in gradle release variant "debuggable true"

This is my first experience with Google Play Billing. I've been striving to follow the documentation steps https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing, however some steps are not very clear :(

I'd like some help understanding what I'm still doing wrong, as it won't be productive for me to test on the store app.